# Creating a key array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and am sure there's a better way to do this, but heres what I have.

Basically I've got an input field and a submit. The user can input their zip code to find a sales rep that covers their zipcode. I've got a short list of sales reps with zip code ranges to define their territories. I've got this working with the below code

```
var zipRange = {
    "john-smith":{
        "min":06001,
        "max":06098,
        "label":"john-smith"
    },
    "john-doe":{
        "min":10101,
        "max":11900,
        "label":"john-doe"
    },
};

jQuery( ".rep-search" ).click(function() {

    var userZip = jQuery( ".user-zip" ).val()

    if (userZip.length != 5) { 
        jQuery('.user-zip').addClass('error')
        jQuery('.error-message').show();
        jQuery('.rep-info').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('.user-zip').removeClass('error')
        jQuery('.error-message').hide();
        for (rep in zipRange) {
            if (userZip >= zipRange[rep].min && userZip <= zipRange[rep].max) {
                jQuery('.rep-' + zipRange[rep].label).show();
            } else {
                jQuery('.rep-' + zipRange[rep].label).hide();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

The problem I'm having is that since this company has such a small rep list some of them have multiple territories. I'm able to adjust for this by just creating a second entry for the rep as so

```
"john-doe-2":{
    "min":07000,
    "max":07900,
    "label":"john-doe-2"
},
```

But what I'd really like to do to is include the "min" and "max" keys as an array. Something like

```
"john-doe":{
    "min":{"1":10101,"2":07000};
    "max":{"1":11900,"2":07900};
    "label":"john-doe"
},
```

What I'm stuck on is getting my for and if loop to work correctly with this. Like I said, I'm pretty new to this so if there's an obvious way to do this that I'm missing or a better way I wouldn't be surprised. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Rather than segregating min and max, I would suggest grouping them together.  `zipcodes:[{min:10101, max:11900}, {min:07000, max:07900}]`.  This way you can loop over the zipcode ranges and check each one to see if the zipcode they entered falls in that range.  Essentially not grouping by mins and maxes, but grouping by territories, which relates more clearly to your data model.

Comment: You could also do it the other way around (also to make overlaps easier to spot). Thus, creating ranges and point them to a id or so of the sales guy Edit - or girl...........

Comment: I don't believe zip codes are linear. Have you thought about making an array of zip codes each rep? Then you could `.filter()` the reps by those  who's zip arrays  `.include()` the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'm not sure a range is what you want here as it could include and/or exclude unintended zip codes. I would think making a list (array) of zip codes each rep is able to cover would be a more accurate approach. Something like this:

```
var repsZipCoverage = {
  'john-doe':[10101,11900],
  'john-smith':[06001,06098],
  'john-wick':[06001,06098,10101,11900]
};

jQuery('.rep-search').on('click', function() {
  let $userZip = jQuery('.user-zip');
  let userZip = parseInt($userZip.val(), 10);

  jQuery('.rep-info').hide(); //assuming each rep also has a class of rep-info

  if ($userZip.val().length != 5) { 
    $userZip.addClass('error');
    jQuery('.error-message').show();
  } else {
    $userZip.removeClass('error');
    jQuery('.error-message').hide();        

    $.each(repZipCoverage, function(rep, coverage) {
        if (coverage.includes(userZip)) { $(`.rep-${rep}`).show(); }
    });
  }
});
```

Another thought to mention, if you use numbers (not quoted 10101) in your array you'll need to parseInt() the input, as input values return strings. Or you could just put strings in the array (quoted '10101' or "10101").

EDIT: Since you mentioned you're pretty new, I should also mention I'm using a template literal at the end. Evaluates to `$('.rep-' + rep)`. Doesn't make a big difference here, but some code it makes the code much more human readable, so I use them alot. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals